# Is there a way of inputting an object to the attr() method in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm using d3, javascript and the `attr()` method

my code looks similar to this

```
d3.attr("height", 100)
   .attr("width", 100)
```

I want to make it so that i don't have to keep typing `.attr()` for each, attribute method.

Is there a way of inputting an object, to the `attr()` method ? I've tried to do it but with no result.

e.g.

```
d3.attr({
 height:100, 
width:100
})
```